# dynamic array in c with "new" command

Tags: c, arrays, memory

our teacher told us that we can make a dynamic array in C (**not in C++**) using the code below :

```
int main()
{
 int n;
 scanf("%d" , &n);
 float* x =new float[n];
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't. Possible solutions: get yourself a new teacher. Or a new school.

Comment: Ask your teacher to show you how well that compiles with a C compiler. Here you go: https://ideone.com/Zs5dVg

Comment: And your question is what exactly?

Comment: I once had a university lecturer tell the class that ASCII stood for ASC version 2. I quickly dropped that subject.

Comment: Tell your teacher to add these three lines to the top of his file(s): `#ifdef __cplusplus` / `#error bad compiler` / `#endif`

Comment: Someone has it exactly backwards  The `new` operator is C++ (**not C**).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either your teacher is incorrect or you misunderstood - that is not valid C code.

As of the 1999 version of C, you can create a *variable-length array* as such:

```
int n;
scanf( “%d”, &n );
float x[n];
```

or you can dynamically allocate memory using `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`:

```
int n;
scanf( “%d”, &n);
float *x = malloc( n * sizeof *x );
```

but there is no `new` operator in C.